# String reversed when I combine two char in python3 which is not expected

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding

I need to use some special character like 'מ'. When I combine it with another simple character, strange thing happend. The result has an opposite order. When I do '1' + 'מ', and print, I can see 'מ' the first, and '1' the second.

What I want to do is some string operations, save filename using this name.

I check some decode or encode ways, but failed.

```py
a = 'מ'
print(a.encode('UTF-8'))

b = '1' + a
print(b.encode('utf8').decode('utf8'))  # not expected

print(b.startswith('1'))

print(b'\x31\xd7\x9e'.decode('utf8'))  # unicode of '1' is 31
```

Why this happend?

Answer (score 1):

This is not because of encoding, but because of Unicode.

Your string `a` is right to left (according unicode)

The number `1` has just preference left to right, but it will not override right to left on right to left scripts.

So the bytes are in correct order (as the semantic order), but the display will reverse, because it is a right to left string.

You can override order wither in Unicode, or (preferred) with markdown (e.g. HTML elements).

So: nothing about encoding, it is just the way to print right-to-left characters. Semantic should remain between encoding.